# Error in adapter.fill function

Tags: c#

I am a beginner programmer.

I wrote the following code that shows an error in "adapter.fill(dt)  ??????

this code must do the following steps:

1-connect to my dataset that has two fields :UserID,TrackID (2916 fields) 2-Read the dataset line by line and put the UserId of each recored to a url(instead of ). 3-Search through the webpage 4-if it finds the TrackId (exactly the same) which is related to UserId, add 1 to counter.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Net;

namespace test2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\hidden.accdb";
            conn.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = "Select * from hidden.accdb";
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            //To read data from dataset
            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
            //Store the UserID
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            int UserID=0,TrackID=0;
            int counter=0;
            foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                string url = "http://abcd/<userid>?groups=<userid>";
                var test = url.Replace("<userid>", Convert.ToString(row["UserID"]));
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url);
                string client = (new WebClient()).DownloadString("http://abcd/UserID?groups=UserID");
                if (client.ToLower() == (Convert.ToString(TrackID).ToLower()))
                {
                    counter++;
                }
                int ave = counter / 2916;
                MessageBox.Show("Average" + counter);
            }
            conn.Close();
            }

}
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is invalid:

```
"Select * from hidden.accdb"
```

`hidden.accdb` should be table name that contains the `UserID` and `TrackID` columns. not access database file name

Comment: It is the table name and they are the same.